# Custom Preview/Commit View Controllers When 3D Touching a Link in a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, 3dtouch

I have a `UITextView` that displays an `NSAttributedString` that contains various links (via `NSLinkAttributeName`) and I want to be able to use my own view controllers as the previewing and commit view controllers rather than the default behaviour.

I assume that this is possible because the `UITextItemInteraction` enum, which is used in `UITextViewDelegate`, contains [a case for 3D touching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextiteminteraction/1649138-preview).

I have tried:

- looking for a solution in `UITextViewDelegate` but the closest function to what I want, `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)` doesn't seem to let you change the preview or commit view controllers - just disable the default behaviour
- doing it the same way as you would with any other view and registering it for 3D touch and using `previewingContext(_:viewControllerForLocation:)` from `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`, but I cant find a way to get the link that has been 3D touched

Could someone please let me know the proper way to do this?